Using FILTER formula with a list (range) of multiple column and row criteria (and ignore the criteria when criteria-list is empty)
  |   A    |B|C |D|  E  |F|  G   |   H  |   I  |   J  |K|  L   |   M  |N|   O   |   P   |   Q   |  
--|--------|-|--|-|-----|-|------|------|------|------|-|------|------|-|-------|-------|-------|-
1 |        | |  | |     | | 2024 | 2024 | 2025 | 2025 | |RowCr1|RowCr2| |ColCr1 |ColCr2 |ColCr3 |
2 |        | |  | |     | | HY1  |  HY2 |  HY1 |  HY2 | | 2025 |  HY1 | |Brand A|  P1   | Type1 |
3 |        | |  | |     | |      |      |      |      | |      |      | |Brand C|  P4   | Type2 |
4 |Brand A | |P1| |Type1| | 500  |  70  |  60  |  80  | |      |      | |Brand D|       |       |
5 |Brand A | |P2| |Type1| | 100  |  47  | 300  | 100  | |      |      | |       |       |       |      
6 |Brand A | |P2| |Type1| | 800  |  21  | 200  | 360  | |      |      | |Result1|Result2|       |
7 |Brand B | |P1| |Type2| |  90  |  56  | 150  | 578  | |      |      | |  60   |   60  |       |
8 |Brand C | |P4| |Type2| |  45  | 700  | 790  | 800  | |      |      | | 790   |  300  |       | 
9 |Brand C | |P2| |Type2| | 600  | 150  |  40  |  10  | |      |      | | 980   |  200  |       |
10|Brand D | |P1| |Type1| | 900  |  90  | 980  | 453  | |      |      | | 726   |  790  |       |
11|Brand D | |P1| |Type1| | 125  | 854  | 726  | 850  | |      |      | |  85   |   40  |       | 
12|Brand D | |P3| |Type3| |  70  | 860  | 614  | 140  | |      |      | |       |  980  |       | 
13|Brand D | |P4| |Type2| | 842  | 250  |  85  | 215  | |      |      | |       |  726  |       | 
14|Brand E | |P4| |Type2| | 300  | 324  | 450  | 430  | |      |      | |       |   85  |       |


I want to filter the data in Range A1:J18 based on the row criteria in Cell L2 and M2 and on the column criteria in Range O2:O4, Range P2:P4 and Range Q2:Q4.
With reference to the answer in this question I applied the following formula:
Cell O7 =LET(a,COUNTIF(O2:O4,A3:A14),
b,COUNTIF(P2:P4,C3:C14),c,COUNTIF(Q2:Q4,E3:E14),
FILTER(FILTER(G3:J14,(G1:J1=L2)*(G2:J2=M2),""),IFS(SUM(a)=0,b,SUM(b)=0,SUM(c)=0,1,a*b*c),""))

This formula works totally fine as long as the criteria in Range P2:P4 or Range Q2:Q4 is not empty.

When for example the criteria in Range P2:P4 is empty I would expect the results displayed in Range P7:P14.
However, the formula above returns no list at all. The result is just blank.
How do I need to modify the formula to make it work no matter which of the column criteria are empty?

Is your data supposed to skip a few rows here and there? (from 3 to 5, from 10 to 14), is there any data in your actual sheet?

It was typo in the example. I adjusted it.

Both the given output is not correct!

I fixed it now for both.

When P1:P4 is not empty:


When P1:P4 is empty:


• Formula used in cell O7
=LET(
     α, DROP(A1:J14,3),
     δ, COUNTIFS(O2:O4, TAKE(α,,1), O2:O4,"<>"),
     φ, COUNTIFS(P2:P4, INDEX(α,,3), P2:P4,"<>"),
     β, COUNTIFS(Q2:Q4, INDEX(α,,5), Q2:Q4,"<>"),
     ε, IFS(SUM(δ)=0,φ*β,SUM(φ)=0,δ*β,SUM(β)=0,δ*φ,SUM(δ*φ)=0,β,1,δ*φ*β),
     Σ, --CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(α, IF(SUM(ε)=0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))^0, ε),0),XMATCH(1, (L2=A1:J1)*(M2=A2:J2))),
     FILTER(Σ,1-ISERR(Σ)))


Updated Formula Using Custom LAMBDA() :
=LET(
     λ,LAMBDA(α,δ,ABS(AND(ISBLANK(δ))-MMULT(--(α=TOROW(δ)),{1;1;1}))),
     φ, FILTER(G4:J14,(G1:J1=L2)*(M2=G2:J2))*λ(A4:A14,O2:O4)*λ(C4:C14,P2:P4)*λ(E4:E14,Q2:Q4),
     FILTER(φ,φ>0))



The formula works when Range P2:P4 is empty. Is it also possible to make it work when Range Q2:Q4 or both Range P2:P4 and Q2:Q4 are empty?

@Michi before you typo edit which you have mentioned, i was working on it. I was going to post the answer which i have updated now. You can try, I am finding it hard, i dont know why, when i always copy the data from your post it always carries non printable characters, which dont even get deleted.

On my side it still does not change when I empty Range Q2:Q4.

@Michi you dont need O column to be taken into account for any empty right? Decide first please. This question is only for P and Q column right?

I can confirm the custom lamda is correct. though I would use AND(ISBLANK()) + MMULT(). e.g. you can use =AND(ISBLANK(O2:O4))+MMULT(--(A4:A14=TOROW(O2:O4)),{1;1;1}) to test column A against ColCr1.

@rachel but OP dont have access to LAMBDA() as far i know because they said, they cant use BYROW(), if they cant then how can they use LAMBDA()

I see. then there is no point to work around countif using MMULT then.

@rachel but OP has not stated what they want all the ColCrit if so then I will update? they just col P and Q?

Then maybe they really need to write countif 3 times. like what you do in your 1st version. =LET(criteria1, COUNTIF(O2:O4, A4:A14) + AND(O2:O4 = ""), criteria2, COUNTIF(P2:P4, C4:C14) + AND(P2:P4 = ""), criteria3, COUNTIF(Q2:Q4, E4:E14) + AND(Q2:Q4 = ""), FILTER(FILTER(G4:J14, (G1:J1 = L2) * (G2:J2 = M2), ""), criteria1 * criteria2 * criteria3, ""))

Honestly, I feel they will come up with some similar questions again. so I figure it is just easier to show how to check ColumnA against ColCr1.

@rachel I have deleted my first comment. I asked her, what they need actually? needs to decide and think, as they have posted similar repeated questions multiple times, they are wasting time not ours, but in fact they are wasting their own. With out proper planning and organizing a data one cannot achieve the desired goal!  At least i dont have any issue in answering the question, because if i can i will try, it will help me, but they need to think and decide, so they can resolve it. OP is struggling for many days! I may sound bad,but i am only trying make them understand.Sorry if this offends

Agreed. It is mentally exhausting to struggle over something that is rather trivial. Usually, I try my best to point out to OP that what they want to do is really not that complicated, as long as they are clear on what they want to do. Fortunately, there are guidelines on how to ask questions. I find that when people make an effort to explain their questions clearly, they usually respond better to the answers people posted here, even if the answers don't give the exact results they are looking for, they are still able to adapt it to suit their own needs.

Filter Data (Multiple Criteria (Drop-Downs))
=LET(data,A4:J14,g_cols,{1;3;5},v_cols,{7;8;9;10},
        hdata,G1:J2,y_row,1,h_row,2,frdata,L2:M2,fcdata,O2:Q4,
        if_no_match,"No match",
    GetTFs,LAMBDA(data,g_cols,g_col,fcdata,fcol,LET(
        f,INDEX(fcdata,,fcol),
        IF(COUNTA(f)=0,EXPAND(1,ROWS(data),,1),
            ISNUMBER(XMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(data,INDEX(g_cols,g_col)),f))))),
    v_col,XMATCH(1,(CHOOSEROWS(hdata,y_row)=INDEX(frdata,1))
        *(CHOOSEROWS(hdata,h_row)=INDEX(frdata,2))),
    v,CHOOSECOLS(data,INDEX(v_cols,v_col)),
    b,GetTFs(data,g_cols,1,fcdata,1),
    p,GetTFs(data,g_cols,2,fcdata,2),
    t,GetTFs(data,g_cols,3,fcdata,3),
    r,FILTER(v,b*p*t,if_no_match),
    r)



Here's the markup table:










2024
2024
2025
2025

RowCr1
RowCr2

ColCr1
ColCr2
ColCr3










HY1
HY2
HY1
HY2

2025
HY1

Brand A
P1
Type1
















Brand C
P4
Type2


Brand A

P1

Type1

500
70
60
80




Brand D




Brand A

P2

Type1

100
47
300
100









Brand A

P2

Type1

800
21
200
360




Result1
Result2



Brand B

P1

Type2

90
56
150
578




60
60



Brand C

P4

Type2

45
700
790
800




790
300



Brand C

P2

Type2

600
150
40
10




980
200



Brand D

P1

Type1

900
90
980
453




726
790



Brand D

P1

Type1

125
854
726
850




85
40



Brand D

P3

Type3

70
860
614
140





980



Brand D

P4

Type2

842
250
85
215





726



Brand E

P4

Type2

300
324
450
430





85




